# What was the first superhero team in comics?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero

What was the first superhero team in comics?

To avoid broad interpretations, by superheroes I also mean the ones with or without superpowers just like Young Allies, Batman, Bucky Barnes, Rocketeer / etc.

Comment: @Bat as long as I searched Marvel did the *first crossover* when gathered human torch and sub-mariner in the same issue. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11867/when-did-comic-crossovers-start and little after JSA came with the *first team*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In conventional comic books, this is most likely the:

## [Justice Society of America](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_Society_of_America_(New_Earth)) <sub><sup>[(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_Society_of_America)</sup></sub>

According to DC comics, the JSA is considered the first "official" super hero team to be formed:

> The JSA’s first appearance came in 1940 in the pages of ALL-STAR COMICS #3, making them the very first official super hero team to exist.
> <sub>[DC Comics 101: What's the Difference Between the Justice Society and the Justice League?](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2016/10/20/dc-comics-101-whats-the-difference-between-the-justice-society-and-the-justice)</sub>

First appearing all the way back in Winter of 1940-1941, in [*All Star Comics #3*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/All-Star_Comics_Vol_1_3), the Justice Society of America would become the inspiration for what is currently known as the Justice League of America

[image: All Star Comics #3 cover]

---

Funny you should mention them, because (possibly) the second team in comics was in fact the:

### [Young Allies](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Allies_(WWII)_(Earth-616)) <sub><sup>[(Marvel,](http://marvel.com/universe/Young_Allies#axzz4z4d1vt6N) [Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Allies_(Marvel_Comics))</sup></sub>

Their first appearance coming just 6 months after the JSA in the Summer of '41, in [*Young Allies #1*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Allies_Vol_1_1), consisting of Bucky Barnes and Toro

> ...decided to gather a group together to fight juvenile crime. They gathered Percival Aloysius O'Toole, Jefferson Worthington Sandervilt, Henry Tubby Tinkle and Whitewash Jones together and formed the Young Allies.
> <sub>[Young Allies - Marvel.com](http://marvel.com/universe/Young_Allies#ixzz4z4fjhyF9)</sub>

[image: Young Allies #1 Cover]

---

Coming just after the Youn Allies, in (possibly) third place is:

#### [Seven Soldiers of Victory](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Seven_Soldiers_of_Victory) <sub><sup>[(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Soldiers_of_Victory)</sup></sub>

Making their first appearance in the winter period of 1941, appearing in [*Leading Comics #1*](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Leading_Comics_Vol_1_1), a full year after the first team had been formed.

> The Seven Soldiers of Victory (also known as the Law's Legionnaires) was a super-hero team, active during the 1940's. Its members were the Vigilante, the Crimson Avenger, Green Arrow and Speedy, the Shining Knight, and the Star-Spangled Kid and Stripesy.
> <sub>[Seven Soldiers of Victory - DC Wikia](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Seven_Soldiers_of_Victory_(Earth-Two))</sub>

[image: Leading Comics #1 Cover]

Comment: If one wonders about the inspiration behind Alan Moore's Watchmen...

Comment: @Francesco an interesting point, I've not looked into that one! I do however take the official DC website on their word, although they do have the "official" clause in there.

Comment: @Edlothiad I think Francesco is referring to the Minutemen, obviously inspired by the JSA.

Answer (score 12):

**Justice Society of America** **in** **1940**

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_Society_of_America)

> The Justice Society of America was conceived by editor Sheldon Mayer
>   and writer Gardner Fox. The JSA first appeared in All Star Comics #3
>   (Winter 1940–1941), making it the first team of superheroes in comic
>   books.

[image: Cover of the said comic]

Comment: Hmm, the text on the title page sounds like they just met to exchange experiences, not actually worked together?

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your interpretation of super hero vs. side kick, Batman and Robin were the first super hero team.  Robin was introduced in Detective Comics #38 in April 1940, which would predate the Justice Society by a few months.

[image]

Comment: The Crimson Avenger and his servant/chauffeur/sidekick Wing would predate *that*, but I wouldn't count one hero plus sidekick as a "superhero team". More of a... dynamic duo, really. The Teen Titans, of course, are notable for being a team composed entirely of sidekicks (at least in their original incarnation).

Comment: I would argue that Robin was first, the Crimson Avenger started in 1938, but Wing didn't put on a costume until 1942.

Comment: If you consider Mari a sidekick, the Ogon Bat is earlier still.